# Push Notification Interceptions?

Tags: azure-mobile-services, azure-notificationhub

What is the possibility of inception of a specific push notification being pushed or its response received by the Mobile App Service? Being read if intercepted?

I am developing a Xamarin Cross-platform application based on the current templates incorporating Azure Mobile App Services.

Comment: AFAIK, if the notification message has been received by the platform notification service (FCM,APNs,WNS,etc.), we could not control over whether the notification is delivered to the device. For Azure Notification Hubs, you could monitor whether the notification message has been successfully sent to the relevant PNS and retrieve the response.  Moreover, the notification messages would be en-queued into a service bus and wait for sending to the related PNS.

Comment: For sending notification message, you may manually leverage the related SDK to send the notification. Details, you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Bruce. However, what I am trying to determine is that once a message, as a push notification which was originated by a web-services message on the front end of Azure, has actually left the push notification server, the possibility of a hacker to identify that specific notification, intercept it and stop delivery to the recipient, read it and reply as the recipient in basically real-time with perhaps a max 1 minute timeout period.